# Encoding error even using the right codec

Tags: python, encoding

I want to open files depending on the encoding format, therefore I do the following:

```
import magic
import csv

i_file = open(filename).read()
mag = magic.Magic(mime_encoding=True)
encoding = mag.from_buffer(i_file)
print "The encoding is ",encoding
```

Once I know the encoding format, I try to open the file using the right one:

```
with codecs.open(filename, "rb", encoding) as f_obj:                         
    reader = csv.reader(f_obj)                                               
    for row in reader:                                                       
        csvlist.append(row)
```

However, I get the next error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

trying to open a `csv` file which encoding is:

```
The encoding is  utf-16le
```

The funny part comes here. If `utf-16le` is replaced by `utf-16`, the CSV utf-16le file is properly read. However, it is not well read when used in `ascii` csv files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Python 2's [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) doesn't support Unicode. Is switching to Python 3 an option? If not, can you convert the input file to UTF-8 first?

From the docs linked above:

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode,
>   but it is 8-bit-clean save (sic!) for some problems with ASCII NUL
>   characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the
>   encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like
>   UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.

Quick and dirty example:

```
with codecs.open(filename, "rb", encoding) as f_obj:   
    with codecs.open(filename+"u8", "wb", "utf-8") as utf8:
        utf8.write(f_obj.read())
with codecs.open(filename+"u8", "rb", "utf-8") as f_obj:   
    reader = csv.reader(f_obj)
    # etc.
```

Comment: @_Tim_Pietzker converting to UTF-8 is an option, do you know how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit useful to you. 
Checkout python 2 documentation
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Especially this section:

> For all other encodings the following UnicodeReader and UnicodeWriter
>   classes can be used. They take an additional encoding parameter in
>   their constructor and make sure that the data passes the real reader
>   or writer encoded as UTF-8:

Look at the bottom of the page!!!!